# not found problem on cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG ../

Tags: gazebo-1.4

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

mohsen@mohsen-ThinkPad-R500:~/gazebo-1.4.0/build$ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG ../

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Gazebo version 1.4.0
-- Found CPack generators: DEB
-- Found Doxygen: /usr/bin/doxygen 


====== Finding 3rd Party Packages ======

-- Operating system is Linux
-- checking for module 'freeimage>='
Must specify package names on the command line
--   package 'freeimage>=' not found
--   freeimage.pc not found, trying freeimage_include_dir and freeimage_library_dir flags.
--   Looking for FreeImage.h - found
--   Looking for libfreeimage - found
-- Found PROTOBUF: /usr/lib/libprotobuf.so 
-- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so
-- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so - found
-- Looking for gethostbyname
-- Looking for gethostbyname - found
-- Looking for connect
-- Looking for connect - found
-- Looking for remove
-- Looking for remove - found
-- Looking for shmat
-- Looking for shmat - found
-- Looking for IceConnectionNumber in ICE
-- Looking for IceConnectionNumber in ICE - found
-- Found X11: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so
-- Found OpenGL: /usr/lib/libGL.so 
-- checking for module 'libcurl'
--   found libcurl, version 7.21.6
-- checking for module 'libprofiler'
--   package 'libprofiler' not found
-- Looking for libprofiler - not found
-- checking for module 'libtcmalloc'
--   package 'libtcmalloc' not found
-- Looking for libtcmalloc - not found
-- checking for module 'CEGUI'
--   found CEGUI, version 0.6.2
-- checking for module 'CEGUI-OGRE'
--   package 'CEGUI-OGRE' not found
-- Looking for CEGUI, found
--  CEGUI-OGRE not found, opengl GUI will be disabled.
-- checking for module 'bullet'
--   package 'bullet' not found
-- Looking for tinyxml.h - found
-- Looking for libtar.h - found
-- checking for module 'tbb'
--   found tbb, version 3.0+r018
-- checking for module 'OGRE-RTShaderSystem>=1.7.1'
--   found OGRE-RTShaderSystem, version 1.7.3
-- checking for module 'OGRE>=1.7.1'
--   found OGRE, version 1.7.3
-- checking for module 'OGRE-Terrain'
--   found OGRE-Terrain, version 1.7.3
-- checking for module 'libswscale'
--   found libswscale, version 2.0.0
-- checking for module 'libavformat'
--   found libavformat, version 53.3.0
-- checking for module 'libavcodec'
--   found libavcodec, version 53.6.0
--  urdfdom_headers not found, urdf parser will not be built.
--  urdfdom not found, urdf parser will not be built.
--  console_bridge not found, urdf parser will not be built.
-- checking for modules 'playercore>=3.0;playerc++'
--   package 'playercore>=3.0' not found
--  Player not found, gazebo plugin for player will not be built.
-- checking for module 'gts'
--   package 'gts' not found
--  GNU Triangulation Surface library not found - Gazebo will not have CSG support.
-- checking for module 'bullet'
--   package 'bullet' not found
-- Looking for Q_WS_X11
-- Looking for Q_WS_X11 - found
-- Looking for Q_WS_WIN
-- Looking for Q_WS_WIN - not found.
-- Looking for Q_WS_QWS
-- Looking for Q_WS_QWS - not found.
-- Looking for Q_WS_MAC
-- Looking for Q_WS_MAC - not found.
-- Found Qt4: /usr/bin/qmake (found version "4.7.4")
-- Boost version: 1.46.1
-- Boost version: 1.46.1
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   thread
--   signals
--   system
--   filesystem
--   program_options
--   regex
--   iostreams
--   date_time
-- Looking for urdf_model/model.h - not found
--  model.h not found. urdf parser will not be built
-- Looking for urdf_parser/urdf_parser.h - not found
--  urdf_parser.h not found. urdf parser will not be built
-- Looking for console_bridge/console.h - not found
--  console.h not found. urdf parser (depends on console_bridge) will not be built
-- Looking for ltdl.h - found
-- Looking for libltdl - found
-- Looking for dlfcn.h - found
-- Looking for libdl - found

-- ----------------------------------------

-- 
SSE4 disabled.

-- 

====== Configuring 3rd Party Packages ======

-- Performing Test HAVE_ALLOCA
-- Performing Test HAVE_ALLOCA - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_ATAN2F
-- Performing Test HAVE_ATAN2F - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_COPYSIGN
-- Performing Test HAVE_COPYSIGN - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_COPYSIGNF
-- Performing Test HAVE_COPYSIGNF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_COSF
-- Performing Test HAVE_COSF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_FABSF
-- Performing Test HAVE_FABSF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_FLOOR
-- Performing Test HAVE_FLOOR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_FMODF
-- Performing Test HAVE_FMODF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_GETTIMEOFDAY
-- Performing Test HAVE_GETTIMEOFDAY - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_ISNAN
-- Performing Test HAVE_ISNAN - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_ISNANF
-- Performing Test HAVE_ISNANF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_MALLOC
-- Performing Test HAVE_MALLOC - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_MEMMOVE
-- Performing Test HAVE_MEMMOVE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_MEMSET
-- Performing Test HAVE_MEMSET - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_REALLOC
-- Performing Test HAVE_REALLOC - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_SELECT
-- Performing Test HAVE_SELECT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_SINF
-- Performing Test HAVE_SINF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_SPRINTF
-- Performing Test HAVE_SPRINTF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_SQRT
-- Performing Test HAVE_SQRT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_SQRTF
-- Performing Test HAVE_SQRTF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_VPRINTF
-- Performing Test HAVE_VPRINTF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_VSNPRINTF
-- Performing Test HAVE_VSNPRINTF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_SNPRINTF
-- Performing Test HAVE_SNPRINTF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_LIMITS
-- Performing Test HAVE_LIMITS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_BOOST_SHARED_ARRAY_HPP
-- Performing Test HAVE_BOOST_SHARED_ARRAY_HPP - Success
-- Looking for include files HAVE_ALLOCA_H
-- Looking for include files HAVE_ALLOCA_H - found
-- Looking for include files HAVE_DLFCN_H
-- Looking for include files HAVE_DLFCN_H - found
-- Looking for include files HAVE_FLOAT_H
-- Looking for include files HAVE_FLOAT_H - found
-- Looking for include files HAVE_INTTYPES_H
-- Looking for include files HAVE_INTTYPES_H - found
-- Looking for include files HAVE_MALLOC_H
-- Looking for include files HAVE_MALLOC_H - found
-- Looking for include files HAVE_MATH_H
-- Looking for include files HAVE_MATH_H - found
-- Looking for include files HAVE_MEMORY_H
-- Looking for include files HAVE_MEMORY_H - found
-- Looking for include files HAVE_STDARG_H
-- Looking for include files HAVE_STDARG_H - found
-- Looking for include files HAVE_STDBOOL_H
-- Looking for include files HAVE_STDBOOL_H - found
-- Looking for include files HAVE_STDINT_H
-- Looking for include files HAVE_STDINT_H - found
-- Looking for include files HAVE_STDIO_H
-- Looking for include files HAVE_STDIO_H - found
-- Looking for include files HAVE_STDLIB_H
-- Looking for include files HAVE_STDLIB_H - found
-- Looking for include files HAVE_STRINGS_H
-- Looking for include files HAVE_STRINGS_H - found
-- Looking for include files HAVE_STRING_H
-- Looking for include files HAVE_STRING_H - found
-- Looking for include files HAVE_SYS_SELECT_H
-- Looking for include files HAVE_SYS_SELECT_H - found
-- Looking for include files HAVE_SYS_SOCKET_H
-- Looking for include files HAVE_SYS_SOCKET_H - found
-- Looking for include files HAVE_SYS_STAT_H
-- Looking for include files HAVE_SYS_STAT_H - found
-- Looking for include files HAVE_SYS_TIME_H
-- Looking for include files HAVE_SYS_TIME_H - found
-- Looking for include files HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H
-- Looking for include files HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H - found
-- Looking for include files HAVE_TIME_H
-- Looking for include files HAVE_TIME_H - found
-- Looking for include files HAVE_UNISTD_H
-- Looking for include files HAVE_UNISTD_H - found
-- Looking for include files HAVE_OBSTACK
-- Looking for include files HAVE_OBSTACK - found
-- Looking for cos in m
-- Looking for cos in m - found

-- ----------------------------------------

-- BUILD WARNINGS

--  **CEGUI-OGRE not found, opengl GUI will be disabled.**

--  **Failed to find OGRE's plugin directory.  The build will succeed, but gazebo will likely fail to run.**

--  **Player not found, gazebo plugin for player will not be built.**

--  **GNU Triangulation Surface library not found - Gazebo will not have CSG support.**


-- END BUILD WARNINGS

-- C Flags: -ggdb3  -Wall -Wextra -Wno-long-long -Wno-unused-value -Wno-unused-value -Wno-unused-value -Wno-unused-value -Wfloat-equal -Wshadow -Winit-self -Wswitch-default -Wmissing-include-dirs -pedantic -msse -msse2 -mfpmath=sse -msse3 -mssse3

-- Build Type: DEBUG

-- Install path: /usr/local

-- Configuration successful. Type make to compile gazebo

-- Configuring done

-- Generating done

-- Build files have been written to: /home/mohsen/gazebo-1.4.0/build
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1720/not-found-problem-on-cmake--dcmake_build_type=debug-..//) by [Mohsen Hk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/242/mohsen-hk/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-03-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2013-03-13**:
What is exactly the problem? There are some build warnings but nothing critical. I would recommend to install ogre support.

**Comment by [Mohsen Hk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/242/mohsen-hk/) on 2013-03-13**:
tnx :) do you have any direct link to0 install ogre?

**Comment by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) on 2013-03-14**:
looks like you are running 1.4, so see the Compiling from Source section on this page: http://gazebosim.org/wiki/1.4/install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Answered in comments.

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0